# ASP.NET Core website select elements option values don't save a "No" value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core 5 application I have several pages of questions where a user will select Yes/No from a select element.
The select elements are using asp tag helpers and are bound to a view model. The select elements are also using asp-items tag to load the options.

The problem occurs when a user selects a value in the select element and then posts back to the controller method. If the user selects "Yes" the value of "Yes" is saved to the database table in the corresponding column.
If the user selects "No" then the value does not save to the database column, and when the view reloads the get method, the "No" value in the select element that should be there is blank.
The strange part, is that if I change the SelectListItem from "No" to "Not" just for the purposes of testing, the "Not" value saves and displays fine.

There are several views in my site that have the same behavior.

Here is my code in a simplified version for space:

View Model

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string PersonId { get; set; }
    public string IsEmployed { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> YesNoList { get; set; }
             = new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem("", "NA"),
                    new SelectListItem("Yes", "Yes"),
                    new SelectListItem("No", "No")
                };
}
```

Simplified View

```
@model WFCDocuments.ViewModels.PersonViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Loan Processing Application";
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card border-1 rounded" style="margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;">
            <div class="card-header">Borrower Information</div>
            <div class="card-body">

                <form id="personForm" asp-action="Borrower" asp-controller="Application" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="PersonId" />

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-label">Are You Employed?<span style="color:red; font-weight:bold"> *</span></label>
                        <select asp-for="IsEmployed" asp-items="Model.YesNoList" class="form-select form-control-square">                            
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:10px;">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-square" value="Save" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is not Javascript that interacts with this form

Controller Get

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Borrower()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
    PersonService personService = new PersonService();
    BorrowerPerson borrowerPerson = personService.GetPerson(user.PersonId, _unitOfWork);
    var person = _mapper.Map<PersonViewModel>(borrowerPerson);
    return View(person);
}
```

Controller Post

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Borrower(PersonViewModel model)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
    PersonService personService = new PersonService();
    BorrowerPerson person = personService.GetPerson(user.PersonId, _unitOfWork);
    person.IsEmployed = model.IsEmployed;
    var b = await _unitOfWork.BorrowerPeople.UpdateAsync(person);
    if (b == false)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Borrower", "Application").WithWarning("", "Update Borrower Failed");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Borrower", "Application").WithSuccess("", "Updated Borrower");
}
```

Unit of Work Interface
My IUnitOfWork interface wraps up all the repository interface which in turn handle the EF transactions of the database context.

```
namespace WFCDocuments.Domain.Interfaces
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        IAddressRepository Addresses { get; }
        IApplicationAuditRepository ApplicationAudits { get; }
        IApplicationRepository Applications { get; }
        IBankruptcyRepository Bankruptcies { get; }
        ILoanFileRepository LoanFiles { get; }
        IBorrowerPersonRepository BorrowerPeople { get; }
        IDocumentAuditRepository DocumentAudits { get; }
        IDocumentRepository Documents { get; }
        IExpenseTypeRepository ExpenseTypes { get; }
        IFinancialAnalysisExpenseRepository FinancialAnalysisExpenses { get; }
        IFinancialAnalysisRepository FinancialAnalysis { get; }
        IHardshipRepository Hardships { get; }
        IHardshipTypeRepository HardshipTypes { get; }
        IPropertyRepository Properties { get; }
        INonEscrowedLoanRepository NonEscrowedLoans { get; }
        IRequiredIncomeDocumentationRepository RequiredIncomeDocumentations { get; }
        ILenderRepository Lenders { get; }
        IInvitedRepository Invited { get; }
        IStatusRepository Statuses { get; }
        IMenuRepository Menus { get; }
        IMessageRepository Messages { get; }
        IApplicationStatusRepository ApplicationStatuses { get; set; }
        ISignatureRepository Signatures { get; set; }
        IUserRepository Users { get; set; }
        INotificationRepository Notifications { get; set; }
        INotificationEventRepository NotificationEvents { get; set; }
        IIncomeDocumentRepository IncomeDocuments { get; set; }
        IEventLogRepository EventLogs { get; set; }
        ILoanFileNoteRepository LoanFileNotes { get; set; }
        int Complete();
    }
}
```

Edit: 2/9/2022 2:41pm
If I change the select element to a plain input element and manually type in "No", the value is persisted and is displayed through post and get actions.
Something is up with the select elements

Comment: What is the value in `model` on the post method? Is it coming back to the controller as "No"?

Comment: Yes, the model keeps the "No" value and the person model that I pass to my unit of work method to update the entity also has the "No" value

Comment: Sounds like a DB issue or something to do with `_unitOfWork` which isn't in your post, so I don't know what that object is.

Comment: I updated the post to included my unit of work repository interface. Don't you think it strange that the all other values except "No" are accepted though? I dont get any errors with the database transactions or in the controller.

Comment: have you debug your code to check when you post the form, the incoming request contained value `no` or some other value? sorry it's really weird...

Comment: Thanks Tiny Wang, yes I debugged the code down to the last letter.

Comment: yes sir, then is there any finding? just want to confirm that the if controller received the correct request parameter.